# GUI components not aligning vertically inside JPanel in Card layout

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, cardlayout

[Image of my GUI.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfE1k.png)

I am trying to add components to two `JPanel` containers and then add those panels as cards. I want the checkboxes after labels in a vertical manner. The problem I am facing is that the components are coming in a grid of two columns:

```
public class MyFrame extends JFrame {

    MyFrame(int width, int height, String title){
        setTitle(title);
        setSize(width, height);
        JPanel internalJP1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(5,1));
        JLabel hobby = new JLabel("Enter your hobbies:");
        JCheckBox cricket = new JCheckBox("Cricket");
        JCheckBox music = new JCheckBox("Music");
        JCheckBox drawing = new JCheckBox("Drawing");
        JCheckBox dancing = new JCheckBox("Dancing");
        JCheckBox other = new JCheckBox("Other");

        internalJP1.add(hobby);
        internalJP1.add(cricket);
        internalJP1.add(music);
        internalJP1.add(drawing);
        internalJP1.add(dancing);
        internalJP1.add(other);

        JPanel internalJP2 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4,1));
        JLabel payment = new JLabel("Payment by:");
        ButtonGroup buttonGroup = new ButtonGroup();
        JRadioButton cheque = new JRadioButton("Cheque", false);
        JRadioButton cash = new JRadioButton("Cash", false);
        JRadioButton debitCard = new JRadioButton("Debit Card", false);
        JRadioButton creditCard = new JRadioButton("Credit Card", false);
        buttonGroup.add(cheque);
        buttonGroup.add(cash);
        buttonGroup.add(debitCard);
        buttonGroup.add(creditCard);

        internalJP2.add(payment);
        internalJP2.add(cheque);
        internalJP2.add(cash);
        internalJP2.add(debitCard);
        internalJP2.add(creditCard);

        Container c = getContentPane();
        CardLayout cl = new CardLayout();
        c.setLayout(cl);
        c.add(internalJP1,"crd1");
        c.add(internalJP2,"crd2");
        cl.show(c,"crd1");
    }
}

public class Jtest {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      MyFrame frame = new MyFrame(300,200,"FirstFrame");
      frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: When asking questions, make the title as informative as possible while keeping it short and to-the-point.

Comment: 1) Try `internalJP2.setBorder(new TitledBorder("Enter your hobbies"));` or more intuitive `"Hobbies"`. 2) When taking screenshots, trim them to the size of the GUI itself. 3) Add `fame.pack();` immediately before `frame.setVisible(true);`

Answer (score 3):

Just change this line of code (in constructor of class `MyFrame`)

```java
JPanel internalJP1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(5,1));
```

to this

```java
JPanel internalJP1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,1));
```

i.e. replace 5 with 0

I find [GridLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html) to not be intuitive. When the `row` parameter of `GridLayout` constructor is zero, then each row will contain exactly the number of columns indicated. Hence `new GridLayout(0, 1)` will ensure that each row (in the grid) will contain exactly one column and it will create as many rows as required in order to ensure this.

Note that `GridLayout` is not the only layout manager to use when you want to place GUI components in a single column. *Swing* also has `BoxLayout`, `GridBagLayout`, `GroupLayout` and `SpringLayout`.

There are also third party layout managers including [JGoodies](https://www.jgoodies.com/freeware/libraries/forms/) and [MiG Layout](https://www.miglayout.com/).

Answer (score 2):

The fact that you are using a `CardLayout` to view one panel or the other does not affect the layout of those panels. Your problem is entirely related to the layout of the 2 panels.

There are 2 easy ways to fix the panels to make them 1-column:

1. fix their number of rows so that it is >= the number of elements that you actually add. Now, you have `JPanel internalJP1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(5,1));` - but add 6 elements. If you change it to `JPanel internalJP1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(6,1));`, you will solve the problem for your 1st panel. The same fix applies to your second panel. Even better, use 0 to make the layout use `as many rows as it needs` (see [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html#GridLayout-int-int-)).
2. use a vertical BoxLayout and do not worry about the number of elements at all - just stack them vertically. This has the additional advantage that they look better, because even if you give the layout more size than it needs, they still stack together nicely: `JPanel internalJP1 = new JPanel(); internalJP1.setLayout(new BoxLayout(internalJP1, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));`

Comment: Ah, the King of Layouts - I personally love it, but it is a pain to learn. It can emulate anything under the sun. However, for 95% of the stuff, `BoxLayouts` + `BorderLayouts` are more than enough...

Comment: Added an "easy" in there to qualify "2 ways". I really believe that these are the low-pain options, and that option 2 is lower-pain (if higher-char-count). I though your comment was tongue-in-cheek, as would be "3. Use multi-choice dropdowns"